# clear URL when route changes

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, quasar-framework, quasar

I've got Vue app with this router file in it:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/IndexPage.vue') },
      { path: '/contacts', component: () => import('pages/ContactsPage.vue') },
      { path: '/settings', component: () => import('pages/GeneralSettings.vue') },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)*',
    component: () => import('pages/ErrorNotFound.vue')
  }
]    
export default routes
```

Inside the `IndexPage` I've created this method to show the id in the URL , so I can use it later:

```
 const setURL = (item: Store) => {
      const searchURL = new URL(window.location.toString());
      searchURL.searchParams.set('itemid', item.id);
      window.history.pushState({}, '', searchURL);      
    }
```

This method works just fine, but when I try to open eg.: the Contact page the URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/?itemid=1#/contacts
```

This is not working, because the URL should be the following:
`http://localhost:8080/#/contacts`

Is there any way to remove the `itemid` when clicking a link?
I'm using Quasar and composition api.

Comment: Instead of your own setUrl function, you should use vue-router functionality for this. Like dynamic route matching. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is in the setUrl function.

When using vue-router, I suggest you try not to interfere with the url manually as much as possible.

If you want to add a query to the url without refreshing the page, you can use the `router.replace()` method.

```
import { useRouter } from "vue-router"

const router = useRouter()

const setURL = (item: Store) => {
  router.replace({ query: { itemId: item.id } })      
}
```

Your routes should work fine when you edit them this way.